# CFOptionFlags in Swift 4

Tags: objective-c, swift

I'm trying to port Objective C code to Swift 4 for some reasons.

Having difficulties to port this:

```
if (!CFReadStreamSetClient(_stream,
                                   kCFStreamEventOpenCompleted |
                                   kCFStreamEventHasBytesAvailable |
                                   kCFStreamEventEndEncountered |
                                   kCFStreamEventErrorOccurred,
                                   readStreamCB,
                                   &context)) { 
        ... 
}
```

Whatever I try to provide the proper CFOptionFlags fails with `Type of expression is ambiguous without more context`. And it is really just about the flags, the rest is clear.

Comment: Update your question with your attempted Swift code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `streamEvents` parameter would be:

```
CFOptionFlags(CFStreamEventType.openCompleted.rawValue |
              CFStreamEventType.hasBytesAvailable.rawValue |
              CFStreamEventType.endEncountered.rawValue |
              CFStreamEventType.errorOccurred.rawValue)
```

Comment: Given `CFStreamEventType` is an `OptionSet`, you can say: `let events: CFStreamEventType = [.openCompleted, .hasBytesAvailable, .endEncountered, .errorOccurred]`, then pass `events.rawValue` to the parameter (which should really take a `CFStreamEventType` to begin with, but I guess they haven't gotten round to Swiftifying the imported API yet).

Comment: let flags : CFStreamEventType = [.openCompleted | .hasBytesAvailable | .endEncountered | .errorOccurred] gives - guess what? - "Type of expression is ambiguous without more context"

Comment: @maddy: This indeed seems to work: let flags = CFOptionFlags(CFStreamEventType.openCompleted.rawValue |
    CFStreamEventType.hasBytesAvailable.rawValue |
    CFStreamEventType.endEncountered.rawValue |
    CFStreamEventType.errorOccurred.rawValue)

Comment: @decades `let flags : CFStreamEventType = [.openCompleted | .hasBytesAvailable | .endEncountered | .errorOccurred]` is not what I suggested. You want commas, not `|`s.

Comment: @Hamish: Yepp, sorry. Your thing works. Sick syntax, nevertheless... Why does Swift make things just complicate :)? Thanks for your efforts

Comment: @decades Swift actually makes it easier. The problem here is contorting the Swift syntax to fit into the old C api.

Comment: @maddy: Yes, I see. Give you that. Maybe I started with the more complicated stuff...

Comment: @maddy After a couple of days dealing with Swift and getting comfortable with it I agree: It's making things easier. And it rocks somehow. It is still a strange syntax somehow, but it's cool.